# There is no alert when submitting a form using ajaxForm plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I have an alert that the form has been submitted successfully? I have already tried to look at the page of the plugin still come up empty handed.

This is the code I have tried so far maybe there is something wrong with my syntax:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){

        $('#f1').ajaxForm({

            success: function(){

                alert("Form successfully submitted");

            }

        });

    });

</script>
```

The code above works and successfully inserted all the data in the forms but the alert that suppose to appear after successfully submitted the form is missing for some reason.

This is the script that the form uses when submitting:

```
<?php
$title=$_REQUEST['articletitle'];
$articlemore=$_REQUEST['editor1'];

include "connection.php";

if (isset($_FILES['image']) && $_FILES['image']['size'] > 0)
{

$type=$_FILES['image']['type'];
// Temporary file name stored on the server
$tmpName = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];


// Read the file
$fp = fopen($tmpName, 'r');
$data = fread($fp, filesize($tmpName));
$data = addslashes($data);
fclose($fp);


$query = "INSERT INTO blog(articletitle, articleimage, articlemore) VALUES ('$title', '$data', '$articlemore')";
$results = mysqli_query($link, $query);
if(!$results)
{

    echo "Saving Post Failed";
}
else
{
echo "You have a new Post!";
}
}//end if that checks if there is an image


else
{
echo "No image selected/uploaded";
}

// Close our MySQL Link
mysqli_close($link);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Syntax

```
         // wait for the DOM to be loaded 
             $(document).ready(function() { 
        // bind 'myForm' and provide a simple callback function 
        $('#myForm').ajaxForm(function() { 
            alert("Thank you for your comment!"); 
        }); 
    });
```

I hope this will help you

Comment: But I want to use ajaxForm() that is I think a regular ajax.

Answer (score -1):

Change this:

```
    $('#f1').ajaxForm({
```

to

```
    $('#f1').ajaxForm(function(){
```

Comment: well you can post more code because the rest of that is accurate.

Comment: I have the whole code here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18801121/there-is-no-alert-when-submitting-a-form-using-ajaxform

Comment: try one thing - take out the "success:" portion so it's just:   $('#f1').ajaxForm(function(){alert('superman was here');});

Comment: post the PHP source for some.php